# How can I calculate total amount using SUM () and CASE () together in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

An example of the Google Sheets file that is connected with Google Data Studio:

| Fruit | Color | Period | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Green | 201901 | 3 |
| Apple | Green | 201902 | 5 |
| Apple | Red | 201812 | 5 |
| Apple | Red | 201903 | 4 |
| Grape | Red | 201902 | 4 |
| Grape | Purple | 201902 | 6 |
| Grape | Purple | 201903 | 1 |

For eg., I want to calculate the total amount for the fruit of green and red apples.

So the formula should be something like this:

```
SUM Amount WHERE Fruit = "Apple" AND Color = "Green" OR Color = "Red"
```

In this example, the total amount should be 17

I tried to use this formula in the calculated field, but unfortunately, it does not work:

```
SUM (Amount) WHERE (CASE WHEN Fruit = "Apple" AND Color = "Green" OR Color = "Red" ) then 1 else 0 END )
```

I get a syntax error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be achieved using the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below (the required aggregation can be selected, e.g. Average, Sum, Count, etc):

```
CASE
  WHEN Fruit = "Apple" AND (Color = "Green" OR Color = "Red") THEN Amount
  ELSE NULL
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/0a0ee6cf-b937-4b32-8108-45ab9dbe771c) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process below using a Chart-level formula:

[image: 3]]

Answer (score -1):

You can just apply a filter on the Data Studio graphic, selecting the fruits and colors that you want!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY({A2:D}, 
 "select Col4 
  where Col1='Apple' 
    and (Col2='Red' or Col2='Green')"))
```

[image: 0]

but this will work too with that example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY({A2:D}, 
 "select Col4 
  where Col1='Apple'"))
```